# Ipad app in different languages

Tags: ios, ipad, localization, app-store

What is the best way to localize my app to different countries/languages?
I would like the user to have an option to select the language he wants regardless of the country he is downloading from.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to provide your application with whatever set of languages is needed.
As for switching, the best way is to actually detect the language and use it. You should not implement some specific language switching method, I mean user should not be forced to choose the language again – (s)he already did during initial set up of the system.

Comment: makes sense, however I can think of some situations where you would like to use a specific app in a different language then defined on the system (different users on one machine, learning new language) etc.